# RDLC hyperlink placeholder mask with pdf

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, rdlc

having used this solution ([Render RDLC as a PDF, with a HyperLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865434/render-rdlc-as-a-pdf-with-a-hyperlink)) to forming pdf links on rdlc reports. Im having trouble masking the hyperlink so rather then the pdf showing the full link ie [www.google.com](https://google.com) it would just show "[link to google](https://google.com)".

I've attempted to use a placeholder - and set the action to use the URL parameter and the text value to just a text value without any luck. Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Hi dan, it would be great if you can provide us with your current code, thanks :)